# iOS Progress Bar - strange gray overlay

Tags: ios, progress-bar, ios7, overlay

I am doing a project, where I need a custom progress bar, so I created my own class for a progress bar, which is a subclass of UIProgressView. I the drawRect method I am doing some CoreGraphics stuff for designing.

I placed a UIView in my storyboard, and changed the class to ProgressBar, which is my own class.

When I run the project in the iOS 7 simulator, there is a strange grey overlay on the progress bar. I don't know how to remove it, so maybe you can help me.

Here is a screenshot from the simulator:
http://abload.de/img/screenshotatokt0514-3t5ugr.png

Thank you,
jomo

Comment: Why subclass `UIProgressView`? Why not set the `progressImage` to get the custom look? Otherwise create your `ProgressBar` class such that it extends `UIView`, not `UIProgressView` and make it do what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to know that UIProgressView in iOS7 have different internal subviews structure. iOS6 progress view is a single view while iOS7 progressView has few additional subviews.

You need to loop over these views for more customization:

```
NSArray *subViews = self.subviews;
for(UIView *view in subViews){
    // customize or maybe removeFromSuperview
}
```

Comment: Thank you, "removeFromSuperview" helped me a lot! SOLVED